# Dynamics 365 9.1 - Import data from excel for external entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to import data describing contacts from excel file.
Under my Contact entity Iv'e created a relationship to a new customized entity (Source).
How can I import data about my contacts from excel file including the Source which is a different entity Iv'e created?

When I import the data, there's no option to mention that the Source field is a lookup to another entity.

Thanks everyone,
Idan

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your Contact import file you can add a column to identify the Source. The most obvious options would be the name or the ID.

Here's an example of adding the Account name to a Contact import:

[image: Contact Import]

When you do the mapping, you can tell it which field on the Source entity to map to. In the above example, it maps to Account Name.

[image: Account Name Mapping]

Comment: Thanks Aron. What if I needed to keep more than one source? Your solution helps me saving a specific source for a contact, but it may be necessary to add another source in the future to that contact (not by import, from crm itself).

Comment: If Source is a lookup on the Contact entity, then you can only have one at a time. If you want multiple Sources per Contact, you'll likely need a many-to-many (N:N) relationship between Contact and Source. You can use the out-of-box N:N relationship, or if the relationship requires some additional info, you can create your own linking entity.

Comment: But if I use a many-to-many relationship between Contact and Source, how do I import a source from excel file?

Comment: I've never used the bulk import tool to import data to an OOB N:N so you'd have to research whether that's possible. If you use a custom linking entity, you can import to it like any other entity, populating both the Contact and Source lookups via name or id.

Answer (score 0):

During the import, lookup fields will take the right related value by searching the Name of that record like:
CustomerId(string);**CountryId(lookup)**;
exampleCustomerId; **Italy**;

Italy is the name of that specific record. 
Relationship is automatically solved.

Hope it helped :)